# Calculate the cumulative line for bar chart in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I have the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "year": [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017],
        "value": [0.583333333, 0.833333333, 1.5, 1.3, 1.35, 4, 3.75, 3],
    }
)
df

    year    value
0   2010    0.583333
1   2011    0.833333
2   2012    1.500000
3   2013    1.300000
4   2014    1.350000
5   2015    4.000000
6   2016    3.750000
7   2017    3.000000
```

I Get fig and ax for plotting by

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 5))
 
# creating the bar plot
plt.bar(df['year'], df['value'],
        width = 0.4)
```

[image]

I would like to draw a cumulative line from this pandas dataframe?

Comment: What's the logic for that black line? It doesn't follow the bar heights, and it's not cumulative. Cumulative would be `[0.58, 1.42, 2.92, 4.22, 5.57, 9.57, 13.32, 16.32]`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you could try using the cumulative sum:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 5))
 
# creating the bar plot
plt.bar(df['year'], df['value'],
        width = 0.4)
plt.plot(df['year'] , df['value'].cumsum(), c='red')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Cumsum with a separate y axis:

```
plt.bar(df['year'], df['value'], width = 0.4) #plot the bars
plt.ylabel('value') #add label to the left axis
plt.twinx() #creates the second y-axis on the right, so makes sure bars are full size
plt.plot(df['year'], df['value'].cumsum(), color='red'); #add the cumsum line
plt.ylabel('cumsum') #add label to the right axis
```

[image: chart with cumsum]